# Akka for persistent work queue

Tags: akka, message-queue

I'm writing a web application in Play 2.2.2, and after a user updates some state, I need to perform some additional costly processing. I'd like to schedule this processing asynchronously so as not to block the user. One option is to put work items onto a `BlockingQueue`, and have worker thread(s) take items from it. However, if the app crashes, I'd lose the pending items.

Would Akka be a good fit for this problem instead?

Comment: You can take a look at [Akk persistence](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence.html)

Comment: @SergiyPrydatchenko -- thanks, I actually did see that page, but it wasn't immediately clear to me how I might use those features  implement a work queue. Would you be able to perhaps elaborate for someone who isn't that familiar with Akka?

Comment: Personally I still use my custom persistence mechanism (a custom durable mailbox with acknowledgement and cluster-wide recovery) which has been created before Akka Persistence has arrived.

Answer (score 2):

It is late but I can see that this question is not answered.
I found the following links while researching about Akka Persistence.
Check it out and post any useful answer you might have found.

1. [Making the Reactive Queue durable with Akka Persistence](http://www.warski.org/blog/2014/07/making-the-reactive-queue-durable-with-akka-persistence/)
2. [Job queue in b2b with Akka](http://www.slideshare.net/YasukiOkumura/job-queue-in-b2b-with-akka-long-version)